# Linux/Windows - how do you detect being plugged into somebody else's router?

Tags: networking, security

Say you have a Linux-based KVM server, running Windows guests.

This is connected to your own router (pfSense or VyOS).

How do you detect changes in the network connectivity, and take action as a result? (For example, somebody unplugs the server, and plugs into their own rogue router?)

Or should you detect changes in the external IP (e.g. https://www.ipify.org)?

Comment: A router change can be detected if it was not done by pros, but you are watching its MAC addresse (the MAC of your old routers probably you can dig out from some DHCP log). But I am not sure, how your virtual network is connected there, it is a general idea for any network. Pro cracker does the router change (and then the MITM) with a faked MAC.

Answer (score 1):

Physical security for the network gear. Do not let just anyone in the computer room with the servers and Internet connection. Will not detect change, but limits it to a few people.

Port security style L2 controls can lock down a port to certain MAC addresses, like your Internet device.

Flow ingestion tools can take in IPFIX or NetFlow and tell you what IP addresses, MAC addresses, and other contextual information.

These last switch features are somewhat advanced and not on every network operating system. In which case you can use the more primitive method of labeling cables and recording key IP addresses and MACs. Anything foreign is suspect.